Is one allowed to OWN a King James Bible, Koran, etc.?
Halachically speaking (as opposed to a mere Middos Chassidus), is one allowed to own a book or document of another religion? This question can be divided into sub-questions:
1. Would there be a difference if the book/document is only meant for reference, e.g. to quote a passage in an essay?
2. Would there be a difference between books/documents of religions classified as Avodah Zarah [E.g. Hinduism, or possibly Christianity] compared to those of a monotheistic religions, e.g. Islam?
3. Would there be specific differences in how to deal with them as opposed to other books e.g. can they not be displayed publicly because of Maris Ayin?
4. Aside from purchases that directly fund Avodah Zarah, does one have to be concerned about their purchase financing further publications of such material, [e.g. some of the money will be used to print more Bibles or Korans?
Please bring relevant sources. Thanks!
P.S. If your answer would only address 1 of the above 4 questions, please feel free to answer even if you're not sure about the others.

This is not a "one-size-fits-all" question. It depends very much on the individual asking.

What about owning shares of a corporation that owns such books?

R' Avigdor Miller kept a copy of the Christian scriptures in his bathroom

Presumably R Yehudah HaLevi must have had Christian and Muslim texts to refer to in order to write The Kuzari.

I think the question is not clear enough because what's the practical implemation of owning such a book? If it is to read the book, i guess then we can start talking because owning a book for decorating the book shelve doesn't make sense

Practically in my case, I was curious because I like to study to see the translation differences between a KJV and a Frum way of reading the Pesukim. as well as not being an am haaretz in these inyanim for your own good. That is a separate Shaila whether it is muttar to do so or not. I'm asking here that, strictly, al pi Halacha, would it be muttar to only OWN such books and not necessarily studying them.

@TORAHistheikur you state here in the comments "Practically in my case..." friendly reminder, that this site is intended as informational and not as a replacement for practical guidance. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi

Maharam Shik Siman 66, Igrot Moshe Yoreah Deah 2:172, Shevet Halevi 3:145, Yechaveh Daat 3:79, Tzitz Eliezer 15:32 Seif Katan 3 etc, all deal with a similar question, I don't have the time to type it out right now but feel free to look inside
